# Set max count in for statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model with a nested collection:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
        this.OtherPart = new HashSet<OtherPart>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int SomeClassId { get; set; }
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherData { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OtherPart> OtherParts { get; set; }

    public void CreateOthers(int count = 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            OtherParts.Add(new OtherPart());
        }
    }
}
```

with this Controller action:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var abc = new SomeClass();
    abc.CreateOthers();

    return View(abc);
}
```

and it works perfectly.  The problem I now have is that for my use case i need to set a maximum number of items to create ( in this case 5).

I have tried the following modification in the void above, but it is ignored:

```
public void CreateOthers(int count = 1, int max = 5)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count && count < max; i++)
    {
        OtherParts.Add(new OtherPart());
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to effectively limit the max number of items added to the nested collection?

Thanks!

Comment: You want `i < max` not `count < max` because your count isn't changing. Also, it might be easier to just say `count = Math.Max(count,max)` and then you can just do `i < count`.

Comment: Why the need of `count` and `max`? Why don't you call `CreateOthers(6)` and this will create only 5 elements?

Comment: why not read basics of for loops and counters this is actually not that difficult understand how for loops work and you can solve this very easily..

Comment: @adricadar: It's ugly for sure, but I'm guessing with the use of defaults, the OP wants to be able to do `CreateOthers(6)` and have it only create `5` because of the default `max` of `5`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. When I implement that change, the view returns 5 instances of the OtherPart. I want to limit it to 5 but not necessarily instantiate 5. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need a custom validator, similar to this:

```
public class MaxItemsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly int _max;

    public MaxItemsAttribute(int max) {
        _max = max;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value) {
        var list = value as IList;
        if (list == null)
            return false;

        if (list.Count > _max)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

In your model code, just do this:

```
[MaxItems(5)]
public virtual ICollection<OtherPart> OtherParts { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to i < max

```
   public void CreateOthers(int count = 1, int max = 5)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < count && i < max; i++)
                    {
                        OtherParts.Add(new OtherPart());
                    }
```